# How to find the limit of $v_n$?

Tags: limits, solution-verification

With $\alpha,\beta$ positive constants, the sequence ${v_n}$ is defined by $$v_1=\alpha, \space v_{n+1}=\beta+\sqrt{v_n} \space \text{for}\space n\in\Bbb{N}$$

I have already proved that {$v_n$} is decreasing and bounded below by $0$ if $\beta+\sqrt{\alpha}<\alpha$. I want to find the limit of $v_n$ now but I'm kinda stuck.

Since {$v_n$} is convergent and {$v_{n+1}$} is a subsequence of {$v_n$}, we have lim$_{n\to\infty}v_n=\text{lim}_{n\to\infty}v_{n+1}=v$.

$v=\beta+\sqrt{v}$

$v=\frac{2\beta+1\pm\sqrt{4\beta+1}}{2}$

This is where I am stuck. Which one is the right limit? There cannot be two limits right? Am I doing
this right at all?

Comment: The "right" limit depends on $\alpha$ and $\beta$. What is known about them?

Comment: How did you manage to prove the sequence is descending? If you did induction (and I can't see any other way), how did you prove that $\;v_2\le v_1\;$ ...? That depends heavily on $\;\alpha,\,\beta\;$ ...

Comment: $\alpha,\beta$ are positive constants

Comment: $\beta+\sqrt{\alpha}<\alpha$

Comment: What matters is how $\alpha$ is situated relative to the two roots. Below both, above both, in between?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly $v = \beta + \sqrt{v} \implies v - \beta = \sqrt{v} \ge 0$

If $v = \frac{2 \beta + 1 - \sqrt{4 \beta + 1}}{2}$ then $v - \beta = \frac{1 - \sqrt{4 \beta + 1}}{2} \lt 0$, a contradiction.

Hence $v = \frac{2 \beta + 1 + \sqrt{4 \beta + 1}}{2}$